# How to use WHERE clause with a PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

Why, do my where clauses here get ignored, it's summing invoices regardless of the valued entered as parameters, spent hours on this and going mad!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Usp_custom_dash_metric_invoicespend] 
  @CompanyGUID  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
  @UserGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
  @CompanyUserGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
  @InvoiceYearFrom CHAR(4), 
  @InvoiceYearTo CHAR(4), 
  @CompanySupplierGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
AS 
BEGIN 
 WITH _d 
   AS (SELECT a.totalgrossvaluehome1 AS tgvh1, 
              invoicedate            AS ind, 
              c.guid                 AS cug, 
              a.companysupplierguid  AS cus, 
              c.userguid             AS ug, 
              b.guid                 AS cg 
       FROM   invoices a (nolock) 
              JOIN companies b (nolock) 
                ON ( a.companyguid = b.guid ) 
              JOIN companyusers c (nolock) 
                ON ( c.userguid = a.createdbyguid ) 
       WHERE  a.invoicedate BETWEEN Cast(Isnull(NULL, Cast(Datepart(year 
                                         , 
                                         Dateadd( 
                                         year, -1, 
                                                 Getdate()))AS NVARCHAR( 
                                         max 
                                         ))) 
                                         + '-01-01' AS DATETIME) AND 
                                    Cast( 
              Isnull(NULL, Cast(Datepart(year, 
              Getdate() 
              )AS 
              NVARCHAR(max))) 
              + '-12-31' AS DATETIME) 
              AND c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID 
               OR @CompanyUserGUID IS NULL 
                  AND a.companysupplierguid = @CompanySupplierGUID 
               OR @CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL 
                  AND c.userguid = @UserGUID 
               OR @UserGUID IS NULL 
                  AND a.companyguid = @CompanyGUID 
               OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL) 
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT Year(ind)                    AS [ayear], 
             LEFT(Datename(month, ind), 3)AS [amonth], 
             Isnull(tgvh1, 0)             AS Amount 
      FROM   _d 
      WHERE  cug = @CompanyUserGUID 
              OR @CompanyUserGUID IS NULL 
                 AND cus = @CompanySupplierGUID 
              OR @CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL 
                 AND ug = @UserGUID 
              OR @UserGUID IS NULL 
                 AND cg = @CompanyGUID 
              OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL)s 
     PIVOT ( Sum(amount) 
           FOR [amonth] IN (jan, 
                            feb, 
                            mar, 
                            apr, 
                            may, 
                            jun, 
                            jul, 
                            aug, 
                            sep, 
                            oct, 
                            nov, 
                            dec) )AS pivotal 
WHERE  pivotal.ayear >= Isnull(@InvoiceYearFrom, Datepart(year, 
                                               Dateadd(year, -1, 
                                                      Getdate() 
                                               ))) 
     AND pivotal.ayear <= Isnull(@InvoiceYearTo, Datepart(year, Getdate( 
                                                 )) 
                          ) 
ORDER  BY [ayear] 
END
```

It's this bit specifically:

```
WHERE  a.invoicedate BETWEEN Cast(Isnull(@InvoiceDateFrom, Cast(Datepart(year 
                                         , 
                                         Dateadd( 
                                         year, -1, 
                                                 Getdate()))AS NVARCHAR( 
                                         max 
                                         ))) 
                                         + '-01-01' AS DATETIME) AND 
                                    Cast( 
              Isnull(@InvoiceDateTo, Cast(Datepart(year, 
              Getdate() 
              )AS 
              NVARCHAR(max))) 
              + '-12-31' AS DATETIME) 
              AND c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID 
               OR @CompanyUserGUID IS NULL 
                  AND a.companysupplierguid = @CompanySupplierGUID 
               OR @CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL 
                  AND c.userguid = @UserGUID 
               OR @UserGUID IS NULL 
                  AND a.companyguid = @CompanyGUID 
               OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL)
```

eg, the data returned in the pivot is summing all data (I assumed because it's taking the data from a CTX that it would include the filtered data, so I would expect if I passed in @Userguid = (a real user id) it would restrict the pivoted counts to that of invoices just for the user... it does not :'(

Comment: If you run the query without the pivot portion are you returning the correct with the WHERE clause?

Comment: Yep, the data returned from the CTX is filtered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your `WHERE` clause, I see `OR` being used on ungrouped statements.  I think you want to replace your last chunk of your `WHERE` clause with the following (note that you'll want an extra closing paren afterward to end your CTE):

```
AND (c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID    -- Added opening paren (required)
 OR (@CompanyUserGUID IS NULL     -- Added parens around group (optional)
    AND a.companysupplierguid = @CompanySupplierGUID)
 OR (@CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL -- Added parens around group (optional)
    AND c.userguid = @UserGUID)
 OR (@UserGUID IS NULL            -- Added parens around group (optional)
    AND a.companyguid = @CompanyGUID)
 OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL)         -- Added closing paren
```

**Update**

Looking at the contents of your `WHERE` clause a bit more closely, I think you may want to add a bunch of additional groupings.  From what I can tell, I think your intent is to only checks a GUID parameter if **all previous** GUID parameters were `NULL`.  Your current `WHERE` clause checks all GUID parameters where the previous one (but not necessarily the one before that) was `NULL`.  These groupings should solve that issue.

```
AND (c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID
    OR (   @CompanyUserGUID IS NULL
       AND (a.companysupplierguid = @CompanySupplierGUID
           OR (   @CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL
              AND (c.userguid = @UserGUID
                  OR (   @UserGUID IS NULL
                     AND (  a.companyguid = @CompanyGUID
                         OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL))))))))
```

**End Update**

As far as I understand order of operations in SQL-Server, the parenthesis around the individual `@param IS NULL OR column = @param` clauses is not necessary (aside from making your intent clearer).  **The opening and closing parenthesis around the grouping as a whole, on the other hand, is necessary.**  Without it, your SQL is checking `(a.invoicedate BETWEEN ... AND c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID) OR [GUID clauses...]`

In addition, I strongly recommend cleaning up your SQL that gets your time ranges.  You can simplify them quite a bit (and make your code easier to read and diagnose) by using the following:

```
-- "Start of last year":
--     Get the number of years from 0 (1900-01-01) to this year from 0
--     Then add add that many years (minus 1 for last year) back to 0
DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
-- "End of this year": Get "the start of next year" and subtract one day
DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0))
```

Note that unless your `invoicedate` column truncates the time, your current logic actually excludes records on 2014-12-31, due to the time-stamp in your filter being 00:00:00. If this is the case, I recommend just going with the start of next year.

Comment: this is deliberate, I want it to drop through and default to the is null value for the time being until it is parameterized.

Comment: @JoshuaHolden I removed the statement about the `ISNULL` usage and updated my answer with what I think is causing your problems.

Comment: -->  Thanks it was my parens!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add proper braces here, grouping the OR & AND conditions are important

```
AND c.guid = @CompanyUserGUID 
OR @CompanyUserGUID IS NULL 
 AND a.companysupplierguid = @CompanySupplierGUID 
  OR @CompanySupplierGUID IS NULL 
              AND c.userguid = @UserGUID 
           OR @UserGUID IS NULL 
              AND a.companyguid = @CompanyGUID 
           OR @CompanyGUID IS NULL
```